# How to set the severity level in allure report, using behave

Tags: python, python-3.x, allure, python-behave

How to set the severity level in allure report, using python behave bdd framework.
I used below one but its not working and is showing me by default normal:

from allure import severity, severity_level

@severity(severity_level.CRITICAL)

Answer (score 0):

Try just the tags with severity names like `@critical`, `@trivial`, `@normal` etc.
It's one of the documented features: https://docs.qameta.io/allure/#_behave
[image]